# How to convert a weird date time string with timezone into a timestamp (PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column called datetime which is a string of form

```
Month Name DD YYYY H:MM:SS,nnn AM/PM TZ
```

where nnn is the nanosecond precision, AM/PM is self explanatory and TZ is the timezone for example MDT

For example:

```
Mar 18 2019 9:48:08,576 AM MDT
Mar 18 2019 9:48:08,623 AM MDT
Mar 18 2019 9:48:09,273 AM MDT
```

The nanosecond precision is importance since the logs are so close in time. TZ is optional as they're all in the same timezone but ideally would like to capture this too.

Is PySpark able to handle this? I've tried using unix_timestamp with no luck.

Edit

Tried

```
%sql
formatw = 'MMM dd yyyy H:mm:ss,SSS a z'
select to_date(string)
from table

Get error:

Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'format' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MERGE', 'UPDATE', 'CONVERT', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'OPTIMIZE'}(line 1, pos 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to take a look to [pyspark.sql.functions.to_date(col, format=None)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date) function.

From the documentation:

> Converts a Column of pyspark.sql.types.StringType or pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType into pyspark.sql.types.DateType using the optionally specified format. Specify formats according to SimpleDateFormats. By default, it follows casting rules to pyspark.sql.types.DateType if the format is omitted (equivalent to col.cast("date")).

So, you can use all the Date patterns specified in [Java - SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

If you want to use the Python formats, then I would recommend defining your own UDF using `datetime`. But, using the Spark one has better performance and it's already defined.

Besides, is it nanoseconds or milliseconds (`H:mm:ss,SSS`)?

Comment: You're right its miliseconds not nanoseconds.  %sql
formatw = 'MMM dd yyyy H:mm:ss,SSS a z'
select to_date(substring(_c0,6,4) ||